# How can I set the permission access of certain users to certain collection or document in the restheart

Tags: mongodb, restheart

In my project when a new user is creating, in the base creates a collection with the name as an user name. How should be correctly set permission section of file  security.yml? In instance, creates a new user with name **userid** in the base 'auth/users' then creates a collection 'db/{userid}'. How can I set permission for this user **userid** only to the collection 'db/{userid}'? I know mongoDB have roles mechanism but I'm not at all understanding predicates mechanism in the restheart. I'm gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have an example in the security.yml file that come with restheart:

```
# Users with role 'users' can do anything on the collection /publicdb/{username}
- role: users
  predicate: path-template[value="/publicdb/{username}"] and equals[%u, "${username}"]
```

Comment: Thanks. But tell me please where can I read more details about forming predicates rules?

Comment: In the security.yml file you find the link to the undertow documentation about predicates